# How do I run a Powershell script and continue using the same window

Tags: powershell

I work for a MSP and we support many Clients with O365. Im looking to create a script where I can log into any tenant online easily and continue in that same PS window with what I need to do (create mailbox, alias, user ect). However if I use the connect-exchangeonline command, it has me log in and then the window closes. Is this possible or do I have to build in any commands I want to do within the script.

Comment: You can run `powershell` inside the current console and if the connect-exchangeonline `exits` at the end, it will get you back to the other PS 'instance'.

Comment: That defeats the purpose of the script. I might as well just type out the command if I am opening a console already. The whole point of the script is that I can right click on the one I want and run it and be connected to that company's 365

Comment: I never had the need to leave an open console after executing a script but you can probably add a `Start-process powershell` somewhere in it and it would work? I am not sure but I guess it could work.-

Comment: Unfortunately doesnt work. Maybe I will just build it with everything just built into it